# Can LSTMs classify multivariate time sequences?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I've been learning about LSTMs and I commonly see them applied to the same type of task. For example, [given a 1D list of values, predict which class they belong to](https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-movie-sentiment-analysis-using-deep-learning-in-keras/). Or, [given 8 values from 8 sensors, predict a state.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)

What I am trying to figure out, is if I have samples with shape (20, N), can I give each 20xN sample a binary classification using only an LSTM? I was hoping to treat each 20x1 column of the row as a timestep. Unfortunately I have only seen examples where each 20x1 column can be treated as a sequence. Is it possible for each timestep in an LSTM to have multiple input variables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I have learned that this is possible. In keras, the parameters for the LSTM layer go in this order: batch, sequence_length, num_features